# Use pandas groupby.size() results for arithmetical operation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I got the following problem which I got stuck on and unfortunately cannot resolve by myself or by similar questions that I found on stackoverflow.

To keep it simple, I'll give a short example of my problem:

I got a Dataframe with several columns and one column that indicates the ID of a user. It might happen that the same user has several entries in this data frame:

```
|   |  userID   |      col2      | col3  |
+---+-----------+----------------+-------+
| 1 | 1         | a              |     b |
| 2 | 1         | c              |     d |
| 3 | 2         | a              |     a |
| 4 | 3         | d              |     e |
```

Something like this. Now I want to known the number of rows that belongs to a certain userID. For this operation I tried to use `df.groupby('userID').size()` which in return I want to use for another simple calculation, like division whatsover. 
But as I try to save the results of the calculation in a seperate column, I keep getting NaN values.

Is there a way to solve this so that I get the result of the calculations in a seperate column?

Thanks for your help!

edit//

To make clear, how my output should look like. The upper dataframe is my main data frame so to say. Besides this frame I got a second frame looking like this:

```
|   |  userID   |      value     | value/appearances  |
+---+-----------+----------------+-------+
| 1 | 1         | 10             |     10 / 2 = 5     |
| 3 | 2         | 20             |     20 / 1 = 20    |
| 4 | 3         | 30             |     30 / 1 = 30    |
```

So I basically want in the column 'value/appearances' to have the result of the number in the value column divided by the number of appearances of this certain user in the main dataframe. For user with ID=1 this would be 10/2, as this user has a value of 10 and has 2 rows in the main dataframe.
I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Sorry your question just mutated to something different to what you originally asked it sounds like you want to add the size to the second df and then use this to create a new column, can't you do `df1['size'] = df1['userID'].map(df.groupby('userID').size())`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want to do the following, `groupby` on 'userID' and call `transform` on the grouped column and pass 'size' to identify the method to call:

```
In [54]:
df['size'] = df.groupby('userID')['userID'].transform('size')
df

Out[54]:
   userID col2 col3  size
1       1    a    b     2
2       1    c    d     2
3       2    a    a     1
4       3    d    e     1
```

What you tried:

```
In [55]:
df.groupby('userID').size()

Out[55]:
userID
1    2
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

When assigned back to the df aligns with the df index so it introduced `NaN` for the last row:

```
In [57]:
df['size'] = df.groupby('userID').size()
df

Out[57]:
   userID col2 col3  size
1       1    a    b     2
2       1    c    d     1
3       2    a    a     1
4       3    d    e   NaN
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want.

I want the results of the df.groupby('userID').size() output for another calculation:

Lets say I have another dataframe:

         userID    value    value/appearances
1          1           10               10/2 = 5

Thats what I want to use it for shown in the last column 'value/appearances'. So basically I have another overall value for every user and I want to divide this value by the number of appearances that a user had in the dataframe.

Comment: You can either calculate that as an aggregation or lambda func or just do it against the added column above, either way is fine but if you do it in separate steps then it it's probably easier to do

Comment: Sorry to ask but could you tell me what the lambda function would look like?

Something like this?

df2['value/appearances'] = df1['value'].apply(lambda x: x['value'] / df.groupby('userID').size()) ? 

Sorry if this might be totally wrong, I'm still absolutely new to pandas or python in general.

Comment: `df2['value/appearances'] = df.groupby('userID').apply(lambda x: x['value']/x.size())` I think but it'd be useful if you edited your question to display your desired output

Comment: I forgot to bring up in my code snippet that the value column and the multiple rows of a user are in two different data frames.
I put an output example in the first post, as you suggested. Hope this helps